# adding custom drop down list in tinymce

Tags: drop-down-menu, tinymce, customization

I have to display a drop down list in tinymce. I googled to find any tutorial or any good example but I just found that code:

```
// Adds a menu to the currently active editor instance
var dm = tinyMCE.activeEditor.controlManager.createDropMenu('somemenu');

// Add some menu items
dm.add({title : 'Menu 1', onclick : function() {
    alert('Item 1 was clicked.');
}});

dm.add({title : 'Menu 2', onclick : function() {
    alert('Item 2 was clicked.');
}});

// Adds a submenu
var sub1 = dm.addMenu({title : 'Menu 3'});
sub1.add({title : 'Menu 1.1', onclick : function() {
    alert('Item 1.1 was clicked.');
}});

// Adds a horizontal separator
sub1.addSeparator();

sub1.add({title : 'Menu 1.2', onclick : function() {
    alert('Item 1.2 was clicked.');
}});

// Adds a submenu to the submenu
var sub2 = sub1.addMenu({title : 'Menu 1.3'});

// Adds items to the sub sub menu
sub2.add({title : 'Menu 1.3.1', onclick : function() {
    alert('Item 1.3.1 was clicked.');
}});

sub2.add({title : 'Menu 1.3.2', onclick : function() {
    alert('Item 1.3.2 was clicked.');
}});

dm.add({title : 'Menu 4', onclick : function() {
    alert('Item 3 was clicked.');
}});

// Display the menu at position 100, 100
dm.showMenu(100, 100);
```

This code seems to create a drop down list but I don't know where to put this code or how to use it to display custom drop down list.
Kindly somebody help me in adding custom drop down list in tinyMCE.

Comment: is it TinyMCE 4b or 3.5 ?

Comment: I am using TinyMCE 4b but not sure about this code I just picked this code from tinyMCE.com .

Comment: Where do you want the dropdown list to display(menu, edit window)?

Comment: @loyalBrown yes. how can I do that?

Comment: The example you listed above looks like its from TinyMCE 3. Its quite a bit different between the two code bases. I can show you have to do it for 3.x, but I'm not as familiar with tinyMCE 4.

Comment: @loyalBrown , I can switch to TinyMCE 3.x. Please help me or give me any good example of this .Thanks

Answer (score 13):

```
var myListItems = ['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3', 'Item4', 'Item5', 'Item6', 'Item7',
        'Item8', 'Item9', 'Item10', 'Item11'];

tinymce.PluginManager.add('mypluginname', function (editor) {
    var menuItems = [];
    tinymce.each(myListItems, function (myListItemName) {
        menuItems.push({
            text: myListItemName,
            onclick: function () {
                editor.insertContent(myListItemName);
            }
        });
    });

    editor.addButton('mypluginname', {
        type: 'menubutton',
        text: 'My Plugin Name',
        icon: 'code',
        menu: menuItems
    });

    editor.addMenuItem('mypluginnameDropDownMenu', {
        icon: 'code',
        text: 'My Plugin Name',
        menu: menuItems,
        context: 'insert',
        prependToContext: true
    });
});
```

Then add to your list of plugin when you initialize your editor:

```
$('#myTesxtArea').tinymce({
theme: "modern",
convert_urls: false,
height: 100,
plugins: [
    "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
    "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
    "insertdatetime nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
    "paste textcolor","mypluginname"
],
toolbar1: "undo redo | forecolor backcolor | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
image_advtab: true
});
```

Here's how panel button with dropdown looks like:

[image: dropdown demo]

Comment: Could you explain your answer? That'll help others who see your code and want to apply it to their own situations.

Comment: Yes why not..
On editor.addMenuItem it is adding a menu item to insert menu of tinymce and editor.addButton it is adding a menu item button to its toolbar

Comment: For those struggling to understand [what does `prependToContext` option mean](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34628791/1429387) I provide the link.

Answer (score 5):

First, register the plugin:

```
var myListItems = ['Item1','Item2'];
tinymce.PluginManager.add('myNewPluginName', function(editor) {
    var menuItems = [];
    tinymce.each(myListItems, function(myListItemName) {
        menuItems.push({
            text: myListItemName,
            onclick: function() {
                editor.insertContent(myListItemName);
            }
        });
    });

    editor.addMenuItem('insertValueOfMyNewDropdown', {
        icon: 'date',
        text: 'Do something with this new dropdown',
        menu: menuItems,
        context: 'insert'
    });
});
```

Then add to your list of plugin when you initialize your editor:

```
$('#myTesxtArea').tinymce({
    theme: "modern",
    convert_urls: false,
    height: 100,
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
        "myNewPluginName paste textcolor"
    ],
    toolbar1: "undo redo | forecolor backcolor | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
    image_advtab: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is TinyMCE's documentation for creating a plugin http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE3x:Creating_a_plugin. I would start with that just to learn how plugins work. Then to get a better feel for creating a dropdown menu look at the contextmenu plugin. Copy it, and modify it to meet your needs.

Comment: I'm looking at contextmenu plugin code and I can't understand how & what action is fired when you click on menu item.

Comment: Hmm.. it seems that it's just as simple as adding `onclick` property to menu item.