# Custom drop down menu - Tinymce

Tags: javascript, tinymce, wysiwyg

I followed a question located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16561802/adding-custom-drop-down-list-in-tinymce) to add a custom dropdown to my tinymce but I cannot get it to work. When I add the relevant code around my tinyMCE.init and when I register the plugin I get the following error in my console

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addMenuItem'

My aim is to have a dropdown that when selected will insert content into the textarea. I am doing this at the moment using buttons, but they are starting to pile up and it looks really messy. I'd much rather prefer to have a dropdown so I can easily add to it without there being too many buttons scattered about the place.

**I am sure I have included the relevant files in my header, but maybe that is the reason for the error perhaps?**

My code is located below

```
var myListItems = ['Item1','Item2'];
tinymce.PluginManager.add('myNewPluginName', function(editor) {
var menuItems = [];
tinymce.each(myListItems, function(myListItemName) {
    menuItems.push({
        text: myListItemName,
        onclick: function() {
            editor.insertContent(myListItemName);
        }
    });
});

editor.addMenuItem('insertValueOfMyNewDropdown', {
    icon: 'date',
    text: 'Do something with this new dropdown',
    menu: menuItems,
    context: 'insert'
    });
});
tinyMCE.init({
    theme : "advanced",
    mode: "exact",
    plugins: "table,myNewPluginName",
    elements : "elm1,elm2,elm3,elm4,elm5,elm6",
    theme_advanced_font_sizes: "10px,12px,13px,14px,16px,18px,20px",
    font_size_style_values: "12px,13px,14px,16px,18px,20px",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,separator,"
    + "justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,formatselect,"
    + "bullist,numlist,outdent,indent,seperator,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "tablecontrols",
    height:"500px",
    width:"100%",
    file_browser_callback : 'myFileBrowser'    
  });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I updated my TinyMCE and followed the instructions on the TinyMCE website and it worked perfectly