# `prependToContext` in TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce

Here is a piece of code from TinyMCE [Link plugin](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/link/):

```
editor.addMenuItem('link', {
    icon: 'link',
    text: 'Insert/edit link',
    shortcut: 'Meta+K',
    onclick: createLinkList(showDialog),
    stateSelector: 'a[href]',
    context: 'insert',
    prependToContext: true
});
```

What does `prependToContext: true` mean? I can't find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from the tinymce core (`theme.js`):

```
// Added though context
if (!isUserDefined) {
    each(editor.menuItems, function(menuItem) {
        if (menuItem.context == context) {
...
            if (menuItem.prependToContext) {
                menuItems.unshift(menuItem);
            } else {
                menuItems.push(menuItem);
            }
...
        }
    });
}
```

So, your MenuItem gets reinserted at the beginning of the internal MenuItems array.