# WordPress custom Tinymce drop down that adds a class to header / paragraph that is selected

Tags: css, wordpress, class, tinymce-6

I need to added a custom drop down on the Tinymce editor that applies a class to the header or paragraph that is selected. I have tried a few examples of this I have found on the web but they do not work and are all pretty old. So the two things I need to happen are adding the custom drop down to the second row of buttons on the Tinymce editor. The second thing it to apply the class that is selected from the drop down to the header or paragraph that is sleeted in the Tinymce editor. This will need be a function in the Wordpress theme function.php file. Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

I tried this [adding custom drop down list in tinymce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16561802/adding-custom-drop-down-list-in-tinymce) and https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/192482/add-a-select-a-class-dropdown-in-tinymce but neither worked for me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.